# Why the definite article in “whiskey on the rocks”?

Tags: definite-articles

I am confused as to why a “the” is used in the designator of this drink. For, “the X” refers to an X which I am familiar with. But when I order a whiskey with “rocks” in it, it’s likely that I have no familiarity whatsoever with the ice that the bartender puts in it. So “the rocks” cannot refer to any “rocks” I’m familiar with. Is the usage of “on the rocks” ungrammatical?

On the other hand, “whiskey on rocks” seems much more straightforward to me.

Comment: First of all, *on the rocks* means having trouble. We don't mess with a fixed phrase. Second, the drink name is a fixed phrase, too, maybe punning on the first phrase. Those rocks in your drink do not have to be familiar to you to call the drink by its name.

Answer (score 3):

The origin of the term "On the rocks" comes from the seafaring profession as detailed in https://grammarist.com/idiom/on-the-rocks/

The nautical world gives us this gem, but so do the Scots. Ships in danger of wrecking were said to be “on the rocks” if they got too close to rocky shores. Though it’s been used in this sense for centuries, the more “liquor-laced” meaning made a splash around the early 20th century when bartenders began using the term to describe drinks served over ice. This arm of the idiom came from the idea of Scottish highlanders chilling their beverages with cold rocks from the river.

End quote

So the term is more of a quoted phrase than a grammatical terminology.

Comment: A quoted phrase. Well put.